# Неправильный generate persistance mapping

Tags: intellij-idea, jpa

Почему в idea при generate persistance mapping у меня генерятся два отдельных класса вида, например, Order и OrderPK? Хотя в Order должно быть поле в виде коллекции для обозначения книг, которые в этот Order входят (один ко многим).

Например, как есть:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(OrderPK.class)
public class Order {
    private long id;
    private long clientId;
    private int orderStatusId;
    private int paymentTypeId;
    private int paymentStatusId;
    private int shippingTypeId;
//methods
}

public class OrderPK implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private int orderStatusId;
    private int paymentTypeId;
    private int paymentStatusId;
    private int shippingTypeId;


    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name = "order_status_id")
    @Id
    public int getOrderStatusId() {
        return orderStatusId;
    }

    public void setOrderStatusId(int orderStatusId) {
        this.orderStatusId = orderStatusId;
    }


    @Column(name = "payment_type_id")
    @Id
    public int getPaymentTypeId() {
        return paymentTypeId;
    }

    public void setPaymentTypeId(int paymentTypeId) {
        this.paymentTypeId = paymentTypeId;
    }


    @Column(name = "payment_status_id")
    @Id
    public int getPaymentStatusId() {
        return paymentStatusId;
    }

    public void setPaymentStatusId(int paymentStatusId) {
        this.paymentStatusId = paymentStatusId;
    }


    @Column(name = "shipping_type_id")
    @Id
    public int getShippingTypeId() {
        return shippingTypeId;
    }

    public void setShippingTypeId(int shippingTypeId) {
        this.shippingTypeId = shippingTypeId;
    }

// далее equals and hashCode
}
```

как должно быть (только один класс):

```
public class Order {
    private long id;
    private long clientId;
    private enum orderStatus;
    private enum paymentType;
    private enum paymentStatus;
    private enum shippingType;
    private Collection<Book> collection = new HashSet<>();
//methods

}
```

Возможно, еще проблема в БД, вот схема:
[image]